# Transformación XSLT a partir de un fichero XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Cómo puedo resolver la siguiente tarea, agradecería consejos:

La tarea consiste en escribir una transformación XSLT que a partir de un fichero XML con datos de artistas genere una página web con una tabla con los datos de los artistas.

El elemento raíz del fichero es artistas. Dentro de este elemento hay uno o más elementos artista, como se puede ver en el ejemplo. Todos los elementos y atributos son obligatorios, salvo el elemento fallecimiento.

Ejemplo
artistasej.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<artistas>
  <artista cod="a101">
    <nombreCompleto>Diego Velázquez</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1599</nacimiento>
    <fallecimiento>1660</fallecimiento>
    <pais>España</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Vel%C3%A1zquez</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
  <artista cod="a102">
    <nombreCompleto>Michelangelo Caravaggio</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1571</nacimiento>
    <pais>Italia</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravaggio</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
  <artista cod="a103">
    <nombreCompleto>Herrada de Landsberg</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1125</nacimiento>
    <fallecimiento>1195</fallecimiento>
    <pais>Alsacia</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herrada_de_Landsberg</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
  <artista cod="a104">
    <nombreCompleto>Francisco de Goya</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1746</nacimiento>
    <fallecimiento>1828</fallecimiento>
    <pais>España</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_Goya</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
<artista cod="a105">
    <nombreCompleto>Johannes Vermeer</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1632</nacimiento>
    <fallecimiento>1675</fallecimiento>
    <pais>Paises Bajos</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Vermeer</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
</artistas>
```

Al aplicar la transformación, el resultado debe ser una página web válida. Es decir, tiene que tener todos los elementos básicos de una página web: título, codificación de caracteres, elementos, html, body y head.

Dentro del cuerpo de la página habrá una tabla, obtenida a partir de los datos del fichero artistas.xml.

La tabla tendrá una fila por cada artista mostrado, y una primera fila como como cabecera, con los nombres: Código, Nombre, Año de nacimiento, Año de fallecimiento, País y Página web.
Como se puede ver en el fichero, el año de fallecimiento no está disponible para todos los artistas. En ese caso, en la columna correspondiente se mostrará el texto “Desconocido”.
En la última columna, el valor se obtiene del elemento fichaCompleta. Debe mostrarse un vínculo a la dirección adecuada, con el texto “Saber más”.
Sólo se mostrarán los artistas nacidos despúes de 1500.
Los artistas se mostrarán ordenados por año de nacimiento creciente. Es decir, en la primera fila, el que tenga un año de nacimiento anterior.
Ejemplo
Para el fichero artistasej.xml se obtendrá una página web con este aspecto:

Ilustración de cómo se visualiza en un navegador web el ejemplo HTML.
Con tantas filas, como artistas haya en el fichero artistasej.xml

Materiales educativos de la CAM (Uso educativo NC)
Y este código:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Tabla de artistas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Año de nacimiento</th>
        <th>Año de fallecimiento</th>
        <th>País</th>
        <th>Página web</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a102</td>
        <td>Michelangelo Caravaggio</td>
        <td>1571</td>
        <td>Desconicido</td>
        <td>Italia</td>
        <td>
          <a target="blank" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravaggio">Saber más</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a101</td>
        <td>Diego Velázquez</td>
        <td>1599</td>
        <td>1660</td>
        <td>España</td>
        <td>
          <a target="blank" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Vel%C3%A1zquez">Saber más</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a104</td>
        <td>Francisco de Goya</td>
        <td>1746</td>
        <td>1828</td>
        <td>España</td>
        <td>
          <a target="blank" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_Goya">Saber más</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
...

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola  Toca Retoque, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte necesitamos ver que has intentado, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código como texto, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: yo también quiero la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de utilizar XSLT para crear el documento HTML con la tabla:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="a-partir-de" select="1500"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="es">
      <head>
        <title>tabla de <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*)"/></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="artistas">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Año de nacimiento</th>
          <th>Año de fallecimiento</th>
          <th>País</th>
          <th>Página web</th>
        </tr>        
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artista[nacimiento > $a-partir-de]">
          <xsl:sort select="nacimiento" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="artista">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="artista/@* | artista/*" name="celda">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="artista[not(fallecimiento)]/nacimiento">
    <xsl:call-template name="celda"/>
    <td>Desconocido</td>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="artista/fichaCompleta">
    <td>
      <a href="{.}" target="_blank">Saber más</a>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```